# Can the ball $B(0,r_0)$ be covered with a finite number of balls of radius $<r_0$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

Consider an infinite dimensional Banach space $X$. Let $B(0,r_0)$ be the ball with radius $r_0$. We know that the ball $B(0,r_0)$ is not relatively compact, so it is not totally bounded. This implies that there exists a radius $\rho>0$ such that any finite number of balls with radius $\rho$ cannot cover $B(0,r_0)$, of course  we must have $\rho<r_0$, because $B(0,r_0)$ can cover itself.

My question is what can we say about numbers $r$ such that $\rho<r<r_0$. Can $B(0,r_0)$ be covered with a finite number of balls with radius $r$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it cannot.  For any $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in X$, the linear span $V$ of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is finite-dimensional, so it is not all of $X$, and by Hahn-Banach there is a nonzero continuous linear functional $f$
such that $f = 0$ on $V$.  Take $y \in X$  with $0 < \|y\| < r_0$ so that $f(y) > r \|f\|$. Now
$$\|y - x_j\| \ge \|f\|^{-1} |f(y - x_j)| = \|f\|^{-1} |f(y)| > r$$ 
Thus $y \in B(0,r_0)$, but it is not covered by the balls $B(x_i, r)$.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see how we can take $y \in X$  with $0 < \|y\| < r_0$ so that $f(y) > r \|f\|$.

Comment: From the definition of norm of a linear functional, $\|f\| = \sup \{f(y)/\|y\|: y \ne 0\}$.  Take (suitably scaled) $y$ such that $f(y)/\|y\|$ is near this supremum.

Comment: Thanks, Hahn-Banach is really a great theorem !